# Folder permitions using command promt

Tags: cmd

How to give folder permitions using command prompt?

Comment: I assume you're talking about Windows (for Unix/Linux, I'd expect the use of 'console' or 'shell'). Which version of Windows? XP, Vista or Win7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a command called cacls for this:
see here http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cacls.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: For Win7, cacls is deprecated (run cacls /? to see the NOTE stating so). You're supposed to use Icacls now.